# having big trouble when posting comments to facebook posts by javascript sdk and app id

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

First of all i want to do that users of my site will post comment to facebook profile/page/group feed posts i show in my site by javascript sdk
this is my code -

```
FB.init({
          appId   : 'APPID', 
          status  : true,            
          cookie  : true,
          xfbml   : true
        });

        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.status=='connected') {
                if (response.authResponse.accessToken) {
                   var token =response.authResponse.accessToken;                                                     
                        FB.api('/POSTID/comments?access_token='+token+'', 'POST',{ message:'test' }, function(response) {
                          if (!response || response.error) {
} else { alert('success'); } ........rest of codes
```

so everything works fine.in my facebook application setting's "Website with Facebook Login" section the site url is set as `http://localhost/joomla`.all i am doing in a joomla site module and i will install it in my all joomla websites.i installed in my one online site and when i try to post comment as a different user i get error as follows -

"Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains."

that's because my fb application's site url is not matching with my online site url where i installed this module.so it's look like i can only use the module in my one site by adding that site url in fb app's site url box.so how to overcome this problem?? can i use javascript sdk without app id when my users will post comments to profile or page or group posts?? note that i am generating access token to achieve that and situation is that this module will be used in some other sites which is not mine too so is the problems.please help me all ways with details please.

thanks

Comment: HI ANYBODY to answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple app domains to your facebook app in the `App Domains` field.
That will let you use the app on multiple sites.